# What would the time/space complexity be for this function?

Tags: python

This is a solution to this leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/

I am having trouble determining the time/space complexity of my solution however.

```
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        subsets = [[]]
        for num in range(len(nums)):
            subsets.append([nums[num]])
            for index in range(1, len(subsets) - 1):
                 copy = subsets[index].copy()
                 copy.append(nums[num])
                 subsets.append(copy)
         return(subsets)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain your troubles. What have you figured out? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: If this is supposed to create the powerset, then I think the best you could do for either would be O(2^N) where `n` is the length of `nums`, no?

Answer (score 1):

The work done is linear to the number of (int) values that appear somewhere in a list in the output. This is because `copy()` has a time complexity of O() where  is the number of values to copy, and `append()` has a time complexity of O(1).

Now the generated lists can be thought of as corresponding to a binary number. For example, the result for input [1, 2, 3] is (with binary representation in comments):

```
[
    [       ],  # 000
    [1      ],  # 100
    [   2   ],  # 010
    [1, 2   ],  # 110
    [      3],  # 001
    [1,    3],  # 101
    [   2, 3],  # 011
    [1, 2, 3]   # 111
]
```

The sum of the number of values in each list is such that each of the numbers in [1, 2, 3] is used in exactly *half* of the produced lists. The number of lists is 2 (compare with the list of binary numbers formed with 3 bits). And so the number of individual value occurrences is 2<sup>-1</sup>, where  is the size of the input list.

So the complexity is O(2<sup>-1</sup>) = O(2)